# Install Rocon on kinetic, is it possible?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, multimaster, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use rocon_multimaster on kinetic, but i'm having trouble installing rocon on kinetic. Is it just available for Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276923/install-rocon-on-kinetic,-is-it-possible?/) by [hvitall96](https://answers.ros.org/users/32811/hvitall96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=rocon_multimaster), which tracks the binary package release status, binary for Ubuntu on ROS kinetic of `rocon_multimaster` is now available.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1